# How to build docker image to refer to the python library in venv

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, python-venv

I am trying to dockerise my Django web-application, which run on virtual environment `venv`.

This is my config for my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ppc64le/python:2.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1 
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=agricultureProj.settings.deploy 
ENV UWSGI_VIRTUALENV=/venv 
UWSGI_WSGI_FILE=agricultureProj/wsgi.py 
UWSGI_HTTP=:8005 
UWSGI_MASTER=1 
UWSGI_WORKERS=2 
UWSGI_THREADS=8 
UWSGI_UID=1000 
UWSGI_GID=2000 
UWSGI_LAZY_APPS=1 
UWSGI_WSGI_ENV_BEHAVIOR=holy

RUN virtualenv venv 
RUN source /venv/bin/activate 
RUN mkdir /code 
WORKDIR /code   

ADD requirements.txt /code/ 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /code/

EXPOSE 8005

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh / 
RUN chmod uog+rx ./docker-entrypoint.sh 
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["/venv/bin/activate", "--http-auto-chunked", "--http-keepalive"
```

I would like to know how should I define my Dockerfile so that i can directly refer to the existing Python library and successful build and compose run my docker image for this.

**Append:

This is the error I have encountered after the successful docker image built.

Error:

```
Recreating agricultureproj_db_1
Recreating agricultureproj_web_1
Attaching to agricultureproj_db_1, agricultureproj_web_1
db_1   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: 3: /docker-entrypoint.sh: source: not found
web_1  | ----------
db_1   | ----------
web_1  | ['/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723/agricultureProj',
db_1   | ['/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723/agricultureProj',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7',
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-powerpc64le-linux-gnu',
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-powerpc64le-linux-gnu',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
web_1  |  '/usr/lib/python2.7',
db_1   |  '/usr/lib/python2.7',
web_1  |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-powerpc64le-linux-gnu',
db_1   |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-powerpc64le-linux-gnu',
web_1  |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
db_1   |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
web_1  |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
db_1   |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
web_1  |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.powerpc64le-linux-gnu.so']
db_1   |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.powerpc64le-linux-gnu.so']
web_1  | ----------
db_1   | ----------
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "manage.py", line 37, in <module>
db_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |     "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
db_1   |   File "manage.py", line 37, in <module>
web_1  | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and 
available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate 
a virtual environment?
db_1   |     "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
web_1  | ----------
db_1   | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and 
available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate 
a virtual environment?
web_1  | ['/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723/agricultureProj',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-powerpc64le-linux-gnu',
db_1   | ----------
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
db_1   | ['/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723/agricultureProj',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
web_1  |  '/usr/lib/python2.7',
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7',
web_1  |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-powerpc64le-linux-gnu',
web_1  |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-powerpc64le-linux-gnu',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
web_1  |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
web_1  |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
web_1  |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.powerpc64le-linux-gnu.so']
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
web_1  | ----------
db_1   |  '/usr/lib/python2.7',
db_1   |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-powerpc64le-linux-gnu',
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "manage.py", line 37, in <module>
web_1  |     "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
db_1   |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
web_1  | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and 
available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate 
a virtual environment?
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
db_1   |  '/home/ppt/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723
/agricultureProj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
db_1   |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
db_1   |  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.powerpc64le-linux-gnu.so']
db_1   | ----------
db_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
db_1   |   File "manage.py", line 37, in <module>
db_1   |     "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
db_1   | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and 
available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate 
a virtual environment?
agricultureproj_web_1 exited with code 1
agricultureproj_db_1 exited with code 1
ppt@server:~/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723/agricultureProj$ File 
"manage.py", line 37, in <module>
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
ppt@server:~/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723/agricultureProj$ db_1   |     
"Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
db_1: command not found
Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and : command not found
ppt@server:~/Elephas2/agricultureProj_v6_723/agricultureProj$ db_1   | 
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and 
available on 
your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual 
environment?
db_1: command not found
ImportError:: command not found
```

When I try to docker-compose up the created image, the environment failed to import Django.

Comment: thanks lgor for the edit

Comment: Why do you need venv if you are running it inside a docker image?

Comment: Even in a docker image, you should use a virtualenv to avoid conflicts with Python packages installed by the system. http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2016/01/python-virtual-environments-and-docker.html

Comment: @viveksyngh: to answer your question, all my required python libraries for the web application are inside venv. I have issues to install some of the python libraries like OpenCV, Pillow and Rasterio when I tried to build the docker image from scratch. That's why I am think to refer to the existing python library for the docker image to build.

Answer (score 1):

Don't activate the virtual environment, just add its `bin` directory to the start of `PATH` environment variable. That is generally sufficient.

You should also avoid running your image as `root`. Even in a container that is not a good practice.

Comment: can you advise me how?

Comment: Use ``ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH``

Answer (score 0):

You can use --system-site-packages to indicate venv to use the system libraries in precedence which means change this line and then indicate pip to ignore system installed libraries

```
RUN virtualenv --system-site-packages venv 
RUN source /venv/bin/activate 
RUN mkdir /code WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/ 
RUN pip install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I successfully build the docker image but I encounter error. Please refer to my main post.